# Acces Violation during .png saving

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

When I try to call SaveToFile method on TPNGImage object I get Acces Violation Error.

PNG Construction:
`pngTest:=TPngImage.CreateBlank(COLOR_GRAYSCALE, 16, 2048, 2048);`

Method Call:  `pngTest.SaveToFile('testtttt.png');`

PNG object is created correctly because I can assign it to TImage and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a defect in the Delphi PNG library code. Please report it to Embarcadero.

The defect seems to be triggered by the use of 16 bit colour depth. If you switch the code to use 8 bit colour then the code runs successfully.

There's no simple workaround, and so you'll need to find a different PNG library if you wish to continue with 16 bit colour. I would expect that Microsoft's Windows Imaging Component library will function correctly. Or you might consider Graphics32 with the GR32PNG extension.

Comment: Is there any "out of box" way to save 16bit grayscale image?

Comment: It doesn't look like it, sadly

Comment: Can I simply assign TPngImage To TWicImage? When I try to do it I get exception "Cannot Assign..."

Comment: Apparently not it seems

Comment: I've downloaded Graphics32 from GitHub, how to install it correctly on XE7?
I've compiled and installed packages for XE7 and when I try to compile example I get `[dcc32 Fatal Error] MainUnit.pas(38): F1026 File not found: 'GR32.inc'`